# What will happen to un-updated apps that executes code that requires a permission that the user dis-allowed in Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am wondering about the new Android 6.0 Marshmallow feature that lets users explicitly set which permissions an app is allowed to use. My question is how this affects existing apps that has uses set of permissions.

For example, an *un-updated* application [Target-sdk-version < 23] has manifested permissons to use the camera, but the user manually disallow it. What will happen to the app when it executes code that uses the permission? Will it just crash?

I assume that new applications will have to check if they have permission before they execute code that depends on the permission - my question is about apps that are *not* changed to handle these cases.

Comment: Not tested it, but probably it will throw an exception just like it does when you miss to declare the permission in the manifiest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> my question is about apps that are not changed to handle these cases

The implied assumption is that the `targetSdkVersion` will be lower than 23. Anyone who sets their `targetSdkVersion` to 23 or higher *must* change their app to handle runtime permissions, as they will never be able to get the `dangerous` permissions otherwise.

In that case, quoting myself from [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android):

> Apps with a `targetSdkVersion` below 23, on the surface, behave
>   on Android 6.0+ as they
>   would on an older device: the user is prompted for all permissions, and the
>   app is granted those permissions if the app is installed.
>
> However, the user will *still* be able to go into Settings and revoke permissions
>   from these apps, for any permissions the app requests that are in one of
>   the runtime permission groups.
>
> Generally, you will wind up ignoring the issue. All your calls to methods protected by
>   permissions that the user revoke will still "work", insofar as they will
>   not throw a `SecurityException`. However, you just will not get any results
>   back or have the intended effects. So, for example, if you try to `query()`
>   the `ContactsContract` `ContentProvider`, and the user revoked your access
>   to contact-related permissions, the `query()` will return an empty
>   `Cursor`. This is a completely valid response, even ignoring the permission
>   issue, as it is entirely possible that the user has no contacts. Your app
>   should be handling these cases gracefully anyway. Hence, in theory, even
>   if you do nothing special regarding the lost permissions, your app should
>   survive, albeit with reduced functionality for the user. Dave Smith
>   [outlines the expected results](https://newcircle.com/s/post/1737/2015/05/31/the-new-android-m-permissions-model)
>   for legacy apps calling methods sans permission.

Comment: So, like your example, for the internet permission, will it get a timeout? and what for the camera permission?

Comment: @Nanoc: `INTERNET` is not a `dangerous` permission and cannot be revoked by the user. `CAMERA` being revoked will result in a `CameraAccessException` with the original `android.hardware.Camera` API, as if the camera existed but was blocked by policies (e.g., device admin rules). You should get a similar effect for the `android.hardware.camera2` API, though I forget the exact symptoms.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so using Internet is not dangerous for google...  nice to know.